# Re-transmitting HttpClient request content

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

How can I re-transmit HttpContent of a HttpClient request?

I want to act as proxy between two networks, get http request from one network and pass the content of the request to another while using a different HttpClient (and I want to avoid handling\copying the content of the first request)

I've tried to simply setting the content of the second request to the content of the first request but it cause an exception...

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and the exception details.

Comment: Acting as a proxy server is a little more complex than just passing on the data. You're better off using an actual proxy server software package.